# jquery ajax call returned data

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, ajax

I have the following jquery ajax call, I need to know how can I find the name/text/id of "this" in success function

```
function GetDropDownData() {
        // Get the DropDownList.
        var ddlTestDropDownListXML = $('#ddlTestDropDownListXML');

        // Provide Some Table name to pass to the WebMethod as a paramter.
        var tableName = "someTableName";

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "BindDropDownList.aspx/GetDropDownItems",
            data: '{tableName: "' + tableName + '"}',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                // Now find the Table from response and loop through each item (row).
                $(response.d).find(tableName).each(function () {
                    // Get the OptionValue and OptionText Column values.
                    var OptionValue = $(this).find('OptionValue').text();
                    var OptionText = $(this).find('OptionText').text();
                    // Create an Option for DropDownList.
                    var option = $("<option>" + OptionText + "</option>");
                    option.attr("value", OptionValue);

                    ddlTestDropDownListXML.append(option);
                });
            },
            failure: function (response) {
                alert(response.d);
            }
        });
    }
```

And I have the following webmethod

```
 [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static string GetDropDownItems(string tableName)
    {
        // Create a dummy DataTable.
        DataTable dt = new DataTable(tableName);
        dt.Columns.Add("OptionValue");
        dt.Columns.Add("OptionText");
        dt.Rows.Add("0", "Item 0");
        dt.Rows.Add("1", "Item 1");
        dt.Rows.Add("2", "Item 2");
        dt.Rows.Add("3", "Item 3");
        dt.Rows.Add("4", "Item 4");

        // Convert the DataTable to XML.
        string result;
        using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            dt.WriteXml(sw);
            result = sw.ToString();
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Should it be like `$(this).ID` or `$(this).Text`.

I know the response.d returns XML how can I access the name of tag in XML document retured through Jquery ajax call
Thanks

Comment: i have same question anyone can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand the question, but from `$(this)` (a standard jquery element) you can call `prop('tagName')` and `attr('ID')`.

```
xml = jQuery.parseXML('<Items><OptionValue>0</OptionValue><OptionText ID="12">Item 0</OptionText></Items>');

text = $(xml).find('OptionText');

$(text).prop('tagName') // Output: 'OptionText'
$(text).attr('ID')      // Output: '1'
```

As a follow on, I recommend setting `dataType: 'xml'` in the ajax request since you've stated the server will respond with XML.